# C Realloc error - "Assertion `ptr == alloc_last_block' failed!"

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc, sigabrt

I'm writing a function in C that takes in a linked list and a predicate and returns an array containing all values of the linked list satisfying this condition. Here's the function:

```
void **get_all_that(list_t *l, int (*pred)(const void *)) {
    void **vals = NULL;
    int i = 0; // Number of matches found
    const size_t vps = sizeof(void *);
    node_t *n = l->first;
    while (n) {
        if (pred(n->value)) {
            vals = (void **)realloc(vals, i*vps); // (*)
            vals[i] = n->value;
            i++;
        }
        n = n->next;
    }
    if (vals != NULL) {
        vals = (void **)realloc(vals, i*vps);
        vals[i] = NULL; // NULL-terminate array
    }
    return vals;
}
```

I passed in a predicate that returns 1 always (i.e. get_all_that is basically to_array), and I'm getting an error at the starred line on the iteration where i=4. The error on the backtrace (which was automatically printed from a SIGABRT) is "*** glibc detected *** ~/list/test: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0804c0e8 ***"

I opened up GDB telling it to break right before calling realloc when i=4. I then tried calling realloc(vals, i*vps) manually from GDB and got the error message: "Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-minimal.c: 138: realloc: Assertion `ptr == alloc_last_block' failed!
"

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `realloc` is allocating one too few elements. Try replacing `i` by `i+1`. You should also check for failure of `realloc` before replacing the pointer you passed to it, since otherwise you will get a memory leak (not to mention crash since you fail to check for `NULL`) on failure, and removing the unnecessary and ugly casts from the return value of `realloc` would be nice too.

Comment: That did it. Good catch. Why aren't the casts to void** necessary?

Comment: @Nick: Because `void *` is implicitly converted to and from any other pointer type (in C; not in C++).

Comment: The whole point of `void` pointers (which `malloc` and `realloc` return) is that they automatically convert to any (non-function-) pointer type. Why it's a bad idea (in terms of style, maintainability, and masking errors) is a topic you can do a search on.

Answer (score 0):

And your first `realloc` calls the length with 0, which is a `free`. So the advice to put `i+1` is doubly important.

Comment: That's not a problem in and of itself, because the next call would pass the pointer returned by the 0-size call to `realloc` into `realloc` again. Whether `realloc` with size 0 returns a `NULL` pointer or a valid unique pointer (the standard allows either), the program would work as expected.

Comment: It should also be noted that the GNU `malloc` behavior of returning a unique non-null pointer on zero-size allocation made it harder to find the bug, and changed what would have been an easy-to-catch null-pointer-dereference segfault into a mildly-difficult-to-find memory corruption bug.